# unable to access particular directory

Tags: linux

my exe unable to access paticular directory

it is getting error

> Error Caused : Error Opening File --> ./LOG
>   Unable to open log file,please check the Log path=./LOG

directory exists in same path, with chmod 777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it was my fault exe is trying to access "LOG " (i.e LOG with space at end )  :)